# Real time update of data from another website (or web app or mobile app)

Tags: php, websocket, xampp, real-time

I'm using XAMPP on Windows 7.

I'm building a `website B` such that, when

1. `website A` (or web app or mobile app) sends some data to `website B`
2. then this `website B` (I mean one of its webpage) will automatically lists the data and the time it receives them in a real time manner

... Something like a monitoring board, without having me to click some button to receive data. The data just come to it, and it displays them. (Not something like AJAX call, where you make request to receive data from server. I don't want to trigger AJAX call automatically every few seconds either as it is very inefficient). I hope you understand what I'm trying to say, at this point I'm still worried that you might not. =D

I come across this WebSocket on google and found some chat example.
First, is WebSocket relevant for what I'm doing? cuz this is data from one website (or web app) to another.

Second, if it is, it says that WebSocket maintains the connection, but what I need here is just to receive data from another webapp and display it on its webpage in a real time manner, so, it's really just receive and display, and then their relationship is over. Something like when someone tap some button on a mobile app, it sends the GPS coordinates to the webapp and the webapp just displays the coordinates, nothing more, unlike a chat, so I don't need to sorta maintain the connection, right? Is my argument valid??

Hope someone can answer me... Thank you beforehand! =)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a real time framework. I work for Realtime.co and we offer a multi platform framework. Using the JavaScript API you can push content to browsers, thus removing refreshes or AJAX polling. It also works if the users' browsers don't support websocket since it automatically and transparently fallsback to whatever works best.

You can get a free license at [www.reatime.co](http://www.realtime.co) and give it a try. Follow the tutorials (http://www.xrtml.org/tutorials/gettingconnected.html) and you should be up and running in a few minutes!

Oh and you can use the license on your project for free if you keep it within some limits (1.000.000 messages/minute and 30.000 visitors/month).

If you need some help with it, contact me (scosta at realtime dot co - not com).